# Java - Memory allocation for int value 1 vs 2,147,483,647

Tags: java, memory-management, types, integer

Java allocates 4 bytes of memory to an integer. But does this happen for all the int value no matter what the value is ?

For example 0 or 1 can represented by a bit against a larger value like 2,147,483,647 which could need 2^31-1 bits.

When JVM allocates memory for an integer does it blindly allot 4 bytes for every single int var or does it allocate more memory as the number gets bigger?

Comment: Suppose it did allocate only one byte for some values. How would later code using that variable know how many bytes are actually allocated, and hence can be used?

Comment: But cant he JVM maintain the memory range used for the variable like int var1 ===> 1000000 to 1000008 ?

Comment: One could, in theory, do that (or simply store the number of bytes), but that information needs storage too, so it probably won't even save any memory. And don't let me get started on the ramifications for conceptual complexity, implementation complexity, code generation, performance, allocation choices, etc.

Comment: Yeah storing the extra information on top of reallocation might end up reducing the advantage. Thanks @delnan

Answer (score 3):

An int variable will always take 4 bytes. It would be a waste of time trying to optimize the space used depending on the actual value. The programmer is responsible for making the decision how many bytes he needs for a variable.

Answer (score 1):

A variable of primitive type `int` always takes up 4 bytes (and has a range of `-2^31` to `2^31-1`) and a variable of primitive type `long` always takes up 8 bytes (`-2^63` to `2^63-1`).

What you may be looking for is `java.lang.BigInteger`. It's initial footprint is much larger then `int` or `long`, but it can store much, much larger values than `2^63-1` and its storage grows with the value inside it.

The size of a BigInteger depends on the VM - because the size of an object reference in Java is not the same across platforms, and because the size of an object header isn't even always the same during the life cycle of an object. On a 64-bit VM, it could be 16 (object header) + 20 (array header) + 5*4 (int fields in BigInteger) + 8 (reference to array) = *64 bytes footprint* plus the number of bytes necessary to hold the number.

Comment: I dont have a usage for this, I was reading about the primitive types and this question just popped.